# Data entry user form, copy paste with variation data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a user form in excel vba. The purpose of the user form is to make data entry more efficient. The data that is being entered is for shoe  products. Basically a "parent" of the data is made in one row. The proceeding rows, or what I refer to as children/variations, have the exact same data except certain fields(columns) will be variations of the parent and each variation will have a unique identifier.

For example: say we're entering data for "shoe123". The parent data would be like this
Title               Sku
Shoe123       S123

Then the children would be in the row underneath with the same data except the variation size will be tagged at the end of some fields as well as a unique identifier for each variation. Theyd look something like this.

Title                  Sku 
Shoe123 10.5  s123 10.5
Shoe123 11     s123  11

Uniqueid 
09876543311
09876543321

So at this point I have been able to enter all the parent data in the form and transfer it to the appropriate column. I'm trying to figure out two things.

1. How can I code the user form to allow the user to enter the number of variations to create? and then based on the number the user enters, populate that number of combo boxes with pre filled size selections with text boxes next to each combo box to enter the unique identifier?
2. How would I copy and paste all the parent data with the variation data for each size selected as well as the unique identifier for each variation?

so far I'm thinking I'll need to use arrays for the copy and paste part. I just need some direction. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks Everyone

Comment: I'm not trying to create a database. The resulting excel sheet will be converted into a text tab delimited and then upload into a cloud database. The userform is just to make the creation of that data much faster and efficient. I can provide a sample of what I'm trying to do. However i don't see anywhere to attache an excel sheet. Can you help me out there? I'm sorry, I'm new. Perhaps email me? its my first and last name together +12 at gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you are trying to create a database. If this is correct I would advice you to try and create this in Access. In Access it is a lot easier to link parent data to children. It will also safe you all the time you would need in Excel to code the userforms, etc. as this is (almost) use-ready provided in Access.

If you are determined to create this in Excel, perhaps you could show the vba-code you have so far?